# The way I compute the LC element of the EMC filter using the impedance paper

Tags: diodes, emc, rectifier

I am an embedded system engineer. I am not very familiar with the hardware aspects. I am working in the field of embedded systems in C language and I started a project on designing a power supply based on a diode rectifier, and currently, I am in the process of developing a power supply. However, I have encountered a problem with my approach to sizing the LC filter for the EMC filter.

I have seen a video on how to dimension this LC filter.
here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQkNqY0I02Y&t=1s&ab_channel=Biricha

based on the video

1/ Zout filter must be 10 times lower than the Zin of the power supply to avoid interference between the Zin of the power supply and the Zout of the filter.

My input voltage is 38 sin (wt) ==> Zin = Vin²*µ/Pout
My transformer is 200 VA so I estimate that the Power will be around 190W
So the output Zin = 38²*0.9/190=6.84Ohms

2/ By using theses information and the paper impedance I could find the L and C but it seems to me that the component is very big and I don't understand where the problem is.
Could please help me to figure out the problem? am I doing something wrong in my simulation?

I have a harmonic around 150Hz that I have to filter, to do so I put Fcut at 100Hz. In the paper, I calculated the L and C for two frequencies to see the difference (50Hz).

To test the difference and measure the impact of the filter I added a switch to activate the EMC filter after a certain time of execution.

[image]

with the impedance paper attached to this post, I could find the L and C based on Fcout, Zin.
to prevent the resonance and input-output interruption I divide the Zin/10; Zou<<Zin ===> Zin/10 = 0.684.

I am using a software called Plecs and here is a picture of my simulation.
[image]

[image]

With the values I found using the impedance paper, we could see that the first harmonic is filtered but the amplitude is much higher than expected.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usb9N.png)

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here.  What you seem to be doing, is not generally called "EMI filtering", but "harmonic filtering" or "power factor correction". As you can see, filters are not very effective, so close to the fundamental. An active circuit is preferred. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off with an off-the-shelf DC-output power supply?

Comment: The self-DC output power supply was added for the test, the calculation is purely theoric.  I delete it the source's current peak with filter is approximately 150A higher than the first plot.

Comment: @TimWilliams suppose I have to filter the 3 harmonics at 150Hz how i could do this, my simulation is not a power factor corrector.